# Display value from one cell to another only by mouse click not by keyboard

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code to input value from one cell to another worksheet cell by a mouse click but it also works with keyboard. Please help me to work this code only by mouse and not by Keyboard.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:H9")) Is Nothing Then

        With Sheets("Pricesheet").Select.Range("C10").Value = Target.Value

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That is not possible. This event triggers on `SelectionChange` that means it runs whenever a selection changes. There is no event that triggers only on a single mouse click. Also this line `With Sheets("Pricesheet").Select.Range("C10").Value = Target.Value` is not valid. You should check that.

Comment: You can try if the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event fulfills your needs, which triggers on double click but a single mouse click is not supported.

Comment: is it possible through hyperlinks..??

Comment: Therefore you would need a hyperlink in the cell you click. And checkout the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event.